# pip install producing "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pip, packaging, requirements.txt

I have a package that i have uploaded to test.pypi.

I can install this package in a virtual environment on my machine without any issues using

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ package_name_here
```

There is a list of requirements for the package in a 'requirements.txt' file, which are also included in 'install_requires' in the config dict fed to setup in setup.py.

This works fine on my machine. When I try the same process within a clean virtual environment on one of my groups local servers i get the following error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement widgetsnbextension>=3.2.1 (from package_name_here) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for widgetsnbextension>=3.2.1 (from package_name_here)
```

for many of the requirements in the requirements.txt file.

However when the install bails, if i do:

```
pip install widgetsnbextension
```

pip finds and installs widgetsnbextension-3.2.1 without any problem.

The requirements.txt file was made by using pip freeze, so I am confused as to why it will work without the version number, but not with it.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Does pip throw any other errors, such as failing to reach the target server? Can you directly install from the ``requirements.txt``, or do you have to install each individually? For the test on your own machine, do you use a fresh env without access to the system python libraries?

Comment: try using pip `-r` install <package>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `--index-url` `pip` will no longer install from "proper PyPI", but only from "test PyPI". If instead you use `--extra-index-url`, it will install from both:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ package_name_here
```