# Nexus pypi repository "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pip, nexus

Using nexus 3 I configured a proxy python repository using "https://pypi.org" as remote storage. The url of the repository is "http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/".

Then i used `pip` to install packages using nexus repository, in `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` I have the following configurations:

```
[global]
index = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/pypi
index-url = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/stable
trusted-host = localhost
```

Now when I run `pip search pexpect` it works fine :

```
User for localhost:8081: someuser
Password: 
pexpect (4.7.0)                  - Pexpect allows easy control of interactive console applications.
pexpect-serial (0.0.4)           - pexpect with pyseriat
...
```

But when I run `pip install pexpect` I get the following error :

```
Collecting pexpect
User for localhost:8081: someuser
Password: 
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pexpect (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pexpect
```

Do I need extras configurations in `pip.conf` or inside my `nexus` repository ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install producing "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589673/pip-install-producing-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should change this:

```
[global]
index = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/pypi
index-url = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/stable
trusted-host = localhost
```

to this (swapping `stable` for `simple`):

```
[global]
index = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/pypi
index-url = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/simple
trusted-host = localhost
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can install the packages without modifying the config:

If you Nexus PyPi repository is `http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/`:

```
# To install, mind trailing /simple
pip install -i http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/simple pexpect

# To search, mind trailing /pypi
pip search -i http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi/pypi pexpect
```

Source: [Nexus docs](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/pypi-repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools)